# mongoose Index not created when the function schema.index({ "name": "text" }); used

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrXEo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reAog.png)

schema.index({ "$**": "text" });
schema.index({ "name": "text" });

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const adminSchema = mongoose.Schema(
 {
  name: { type: String, unique:true }// you can create index here also

 }
```

Comment: How please give an example?